# How to use select by attribute or where clause to return equal values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I would like to write a where clause in ArcGIS for Desktop where I make a selection on table one, the clause is `DEGREES = 45` for the second table I would like to find all IN_FID that match the OID of table one, but also select only the rows where NEAR_ANGLE IS BETWEEN -135 AND 135.

How would this be written in the select by attribute box in one selection statement?

Table 1 name is CALLS
Table 2 name is ANGLES

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4.1

Answer (score 1):

The select by attribute tools can´t do a query for two tables at once. What you would need to do is joining the tables first. And then you can easily combine your statements.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a subquery. The WHERE clause for the selection on ANGLES would look like (untested) `"NEAR_ANGLE" >= -135 AND "NEAR_ANGLE" <= 135 AND IN_FID IN (SELECT OID FROM CALLS WHERE "DEGREES" = 45)`.

ArcGIS Help Reference: "SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS"